# One jQuery selector doesn't work on safari. What's wrong?

Tags: jquery, safari, jquery-selectors

I have a form with four input fields. For the validation, I use a small javascript. This works in every browser but not on Safari IOS mobile.

If i remove the line `var incomeBack = $("#incomeBack").val();` everything works fine. I can't find the problem in this line. What's wrong?

```
function required(){
    var incomeFuture    = $("#incomeFutureShort").val();
    var name            = $("#Shortcut option:selected").text();
    var incomeBack      = $("#incomeBack").val();
    var check           = 0;
    var empt            = $("#Shortcut").val();

  if (empt == ""){
        alert("Bitte wählen Sie für die Schnelleingabe eine Person aus.");
        return false;
        check++;
    }


    if (incomeFuture == ""){
        alert("Bitte geben Sie ein Einkommen für die Jahre bis zur Pensionierung ein.");
        return false;
        check++;
    }

//recidence abroad?
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("ckeckbox");
    if (checkBox.checked == false){
         var chk = window.confirm("Hat "+name+"  mehrheitlich im Ausland gelebt? Dann Klicken Sie auf Ok und bearbeiten anschliessend die Detailtabelle. Oder brechen Sie ab und machen einen Haken");
            return(chk);
    }

    if (incomeBack == ""){
        alert("Bitte geben Sie ein Einkommen für die vergangenen Jahre ein.");
        return false;
        check++;
    }

    if (check<=0){
    alert("Ihre Eingaben für "+name+" werden in die Detailtabelle übertragen");
    return true; 
    }

}

htlm:

<form onsubmit="return required(event)" class="income" id="incomeDetail" name="incomeDetail" method="post">
<select name="Shortcut" id="Shortcut"><option></option><option value=5cf627b3db341>Pirmin</option></select>
<input class="CHF" placeholder="CHF" type="text"  name="incomeBack" id="incomeBack" >
<input class="CHF" placeholder="CHF" type="text" name="incomeFutureShort" id="incomeFutureShort" >
<input class="shortCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="ckeckbox" id="ckeckbox" value="1" >
<input type="Submit" name="copyIncome" id="income" value="In Detailtabelle übertragen">
</form>
```

Comment: put other 2 `if` condition before `var checkBox = document.getElementById("ckeckbox");` and check

Comment: I tried your proposal and it does not work